# Can not access wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I was editing my functions.php and try to register jQuery in wordpress. Then I save it and refresh the page and I got this message. I was working online wordpress admin panel.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''jquery)); '
>   (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ')' in
>   /home/blogdesh/public_html/kokhon.com/wp-content/themes/alizee/functions.php
>   on line 265

How can I solve this and can get access again to wordpress admin panel.

Comment: *slightly* more information might be appropriate, don't you think?

Comment: Have you tried undoing your changes so they no longer affect the admin panel, and then make and test your changes offline?

Comment: I was working online admin panel...There is no option left for undoing.I know the fault. In this situation I cann't access my admin panel. How can I get access the admin panel...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install "FileZilla client" form here: https://filezilla-project.org/

Then go to file -> Site manager -> new site. 
Enter the host, username and password. You can get these form your hosting provider ( use logon type normal ). then click connect

In the right panel you will see the server files.
navigate to: public_html/kokhon.com/wp-content/themes/alizee/
download the functions.php file. make the changes and re-upload.

notepad++ is a good free text editor, that might help you.
https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Once this has been resolved, I'll also add the comment to be extremely careful when editing live files, such as your functions.php file. You should always create a backup, so that you can instantly re-upload it and be back at the point you were before you started making changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''jquery));
```

**The problem is that you forgot a apostrophe after "jquery**

Comment: You will have to FTP and change the file that way